# Is it possible to retrieve few records from a stored procedure and in background it will take remaining data in SQL Server

Tags: c#, sql-server, ajax, stored-procedures, grid

I am displaying a huge amount of data in a grid in the front end and data is coming from a SQL Server stored procedure.

The stored procedure contains many inner joins and other calculations so execution is taking around 15-20 seconds which is not at all accepted by client.

So can anyone help me to retrieve a few records first, and then in the background retrieve the remaining records?

I am binding data using Ajax request.

Technology: C#, SQL Server, AJAX, JavaScript

Comment: have you tried OPTION FAST hint?

Comment: can you add some parameters to your stored procedure saying you want records 1-100 then async load the rest of the data (101 - 10000 or whatever) after you get those results? Basically pagination.

Comment: Can you change/ tune the stored procedure?  Why are you "displaying huge data" in a client application in the first place?  Is the user really going to go past the first page or two of results?

Comment: @Flicker : how we can apply OPTION FAST in Store Procedure ?

Comment: @Brad: how we can implement async in Store Procedure side ?

Comment: You should use  infinite scrolling using JQuery and Ajax request.

Comment: It's a query hint. you need to add that at the end of your final query

Comment: something like: SELECT ProductID, OrderQty, SUM(LineTotal) AS Total  
FROM Sales.SalesOrderDetail  
WHERE UnitPrice < $5.00  
GROUP BY ProductID, OrderQty  
ORDER BY ProductID, OrderQty  
OPTION (HASH GROUP, FAST 10);

Comment: @JustinCave :Yes it is necessary to show all data at one place because many other links are dependent on this grid

Comment: You can use paging and take help of http://sqlperformance.com/2015/01/t-sql-queries/pagination-with-offset-fetch

Comment: Thanks @Flicker for query. Eg. if i am selecting 100 records in OPTION FAST, so will  i get these 100 records in ajax response so that i can bind it in front end and meanwhile store procedure will return other records ?

Comment: @HP1104 the Async is not in the procedure but in how you call it. If you are calling this from AJAX then just remember to set `async: "true"`. You're probably doing this already though because `async: "false"` doesn't seem common.

Comment: I don't know how it works in Ajax. if it worked it is the easiest method. I also don't know how GridView deals with it. anyway this is the easiest method and you can simply try.

Comment: @Brad: What is i am calling this Store Procedure from C# backend code. In this case will i get first 100 records or i will get all records together ?

Comment: @HP1104 you can call method asynchronously in C#. look up C# async/await. though if you are assembling your grid on the server I'm not good enough to suggest how you get that second page of data out there without a full post. But maybe if your pagination query is fast enough that's fine.

Comment: If it is on the SQL Server side that is slow, not necessarily the number of records being returned, pagination might not help out.  You need to look at the actual execution plan and find out where the pain points are.